# Ajax not working properly with php code

Tags: php, javascript

1. I am trying to develop a like button but facing problems with the following javascript code:

   ```
   <a class="like" href="#" onclick="like_add(',$article['article_id'],');">Like</a>
   ```
2. now whenever i click on like button,,it alerts me empty text.. it doesn't show success data even though i have provided success value in echo function of php code given below
3. Am i wrong with providing data==success?if no,,then what should i provide in it
4. My aim is to : when i click on like button ..it must call success data from like_add.php and shows 10 as output

   ```
   //like_add.php
    echo 'success';

    //like_get.php
    echo '10';

    //like.js 
    function like_add(article_id) {
        $.post('ajax/like_add.php', {
            article_id: article_id
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'success') { 
                like_get(article_id);
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function like_get(article_id) {
        $.post('ajax/like_get.php', { 
            article_id: article_id 
        }, function (data) {
            $('#article_' + article_id + '_likes').text(data);
        });
    }
   ```

Comment: Can you spend more time formatting your question next time please? We're asking you to use capital letters and correctly indent code... not move heaven and earth.

Comment: i am just a newbie..will try to post questions in better way

Answer (score 0):

where you have:

```
$('#article_'+article_id+'_likes').text(data);
```

if you're inserting into a `div`, `span` or similar tag you need to use:

```
$('#article_'+article_id+'_likes').html(data);
```

or if you're inserting into input field or similar tag:

```
$('#article_'+article_id+'_likes').val(data);
```

EDIT: if not the you could try using `return` instead of `echo` in the php script

Comment: the problem is in following code
function (data) {
         if (data == 'success') { 
             like_get(article_id);
         } else {
             alert(data);
         }

Comment: okay what should i assigned to data?
i am assigning the the output of like_add.php to data..which works fine but i dont know why if part of the code not working...else part is working though

Comment: clearly the response being received is not 'success' as you'll see in my edit I suggested using `return` instead of `echo`, I normally avoid the problem by using both eg `echo $response; return $response;`

Comment: i had used it but nothing happens ...what is function(data)? in ajax

Comment: (data) is the variable that the response is stored in. for example if the PHP script responded with 'success', data would contain the string 'success'.

Comment: yeah thanks for the help..it has been executed successfully..i did mistake by typing id=id=  in my span tag of home page code